# PHP Unit testing a class w/ traits

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, traits

I've just started using PHP and am writing some test for some legacy code.  I have a class here that has a trait.  How can I test that class's method that utilizes a trait's method within a function?

```
trait Cooltrait
{
  public function extractMethod($z){
     return $z[0];
  }
}

class Awesome
{
  using Cooltrait

  public function handlesomething($x, $y){
    $var1 = $this->extractMethod($x)

    if(!is_null($var1)){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

I need to test if $var1 is null or not in the class but I'm using this trait's method.  Anyone encountered how to best mock / stub a trait in a class for testing the *hadlesomething* function in the *Awesome* class? (edited to clarify question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing `Awesome` you can assume that the trait is part of it at runtime. If you want to test `Cooltrait` in isolation, you can use [`getMockForTrait`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html).

In this case; "I need to test if $var1 is null or not", it's the former - assume that the trait is already applied when you're testing it.

**Note:** the syntax is `use`, not `using`.

```
public function testVarIsNull()
{
    $awesome = new Awesome;
    $result = $awesome->handlesomething(array(null), 'not relevant in your example');
    $this->assertFalse($result);

    $result = $awesome->handlesomething(array('valid'), 'not relevant in your example');
    $this->assertTrue($result);
}
```

Since `extractMethod` is public, you could also test that method in isolation:

```
public function testExtractMethodShouldReturnFirstArrayEntry()
{
    $awesome = new Awesome;
    $this->assertSame('foo', $awesome->extractMethod(array('foo')));
}
```

... or using `getMockForTrait`:

```
public function testExtractMethodShouldReturnFirstArrayEntry()
{
    $cooltrait = $this->getMockForTrait('Cooltrait');
    $this->assertSame('foo', $cooltrait->extractMethod(array('foo')));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robbie; I'd like to test handlesomething in Awesome class; I'd like to change the value of extractMethod result from the trait to a specific value.  Any idea how I could mock that while testing handlesomething in Awesome class?

I didn't go into the entire detail of what the extractMethod does in the trait but assuming that it does more than just return the first value of an array

Comment: If you want to mock it you can partially mock the Awesome class, e.g. `$awesome = $this->getMockBuilder('Awesome')->setMethods(array('extractMethod'))->getMock();` then `$awesome->expects($this->once())->method('extractMethod')->willReturn('foobar');` - then use that for your test, e.g. `$this->assertTrue($awesome->handlesomething('whatever', '...');`

Comment: The key point here is that the trait is already applied to Awesome at runtime, so partial mocking is the same as it would be if Awesome literally owned the extractMethod method

Comment: Thanks Robbie; just left my computer but will try this out!

Comment: Works! Thanks Robbie!